# How to control Max Rows in KendoUI Grid based on value in another control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Given the following form:

[image: Grid and Previous Controls]

Is there a way I can lock the maximum row count of the grid based on the value in the CWT box above it?

This is using MVC Razor, with this code to generate the grid:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.grid.min.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.pager.min.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>


<input type="hidden" name="Species_id" value='@ViewBag.SpeciesId' />

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SpeciesRetainedSalmonViewModel>()
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
          dataSource.Ajax()
              .PageSize(10)
              .Batch(false)
              .Read(read =>
                  read.Action("SpeciesRetainedData_Read",
                      "Species",
                      new { speciesId = @ViewBag.SpeciesId }))
              .Create(create =>
                  create.Action("SpeciesRetainedData_Create",
                      "Species",
                      new {
                          species_Id = @ViewBag.SpeciesId,
                          speciesId = @ViewBag.SpeciesId
                      }))
              .Update(update =>
                  update.Action("SpeciesRetainedData_Update",
                      "Species",
                      new { speciesId = @ViewBag.SpeciesId }))
              .Destroy(delete =>
                  delete.Action("SpeciesRetainedData_Delete",
                      "Species",
                      new { speciesId = @ViewBag.SpeciesId }))
              .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
      )
      .Pageable(pager => pager
          .Numeric(true)
          .PreviousNext(true)
          .PageSizes(new[] { 10, 25, 50, 100 })
          .ButtonCount(5)
          .Messages(messages => messages.ItemsPerPage("Records / Page"))
      )
      .Sortable()
      .Scrollable()
      .Columns(columns => {
          columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(180);
          columns.Bound(m => m.MarkType).EditorTemplateName("MarkType");
          columns.Bound(m => m.CWTLabels).HtmlAttributes("width: 100px;");
          columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(90);
      })
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;" })
      .ToolBar(tb =>
          tb.Create()
              .Text("Create")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "float-right submitposition" })
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "margin: -43px 0px 0px 0px;" })
      )
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
      .Name("SpeciesRetained")
      )
```

The form field for CWT exists in the parent view to this view, and looks like:

```
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);" colspan="3">
                <h4>Retained</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <table style="-moz-column-gap: 0; -webkit-column-gap: 0; border-collapse: collapse; column-gap: 0; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="labelCell-smaller" style="width: 15%;">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="dataCell" style="width: 8%;">Total</th>
                        <th class="dataCell" style="padding-left: 12px; text-align: left;">Marked</th>
                        <th class="dataCell" style="padding-left: 12px; text-align: left;">Unmarked</th>
                        <th class="dataCell" style="padding-left: 12px; text-align: left;">CWT</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelCell-smaller"></td>
                        <td class="dataCell">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RetainedTotal)</td>
                        <td class="dataCell">@(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.RetainedMarked).Min(0))</td>
                        <td class="dataCell">@(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.RetainedUnmarked).Min(0))</td>
                        <td class="dataCell">@(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.RetainedCWT).Min(0))</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <h5>Retained - CWT</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                @Html.Partial("SpeciesRetainedGrid", Model.SpeciesRetained)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-pagesize-dinamically)--seems appropriate even though a little dated.

I'd attach an event handler that listens to change() for your CWT IntegerTextBox. In that I'd pass in the value as your pagesize.

```
$("#RetainedCWT").kendoIntegerTextBox({
change: function() {
  var grid = $("#SpeciesRetained").data("kendoGrid");
  grid.dataSource.pageSize(this.val());
  grid.refresh();
}
```

});

Comment: I gotta admit, I'm a complete and utter noob when it comes to KendoUI. I swore off Telerik years ago when I discovered the joys of AJAX. But this project is one I'm taking over on, and I don't have time to rebuild it the way I would want, so I've got to massage the code that's there.  
  
All that said, I'm not honestly sure how I'd go about implementing something like you've posted.  
  
Yeah - I'm that guy.

Comment: @PKD That was me a year ago. Since then I've grappled with Razor implementations of the Grid and pretty much pushed the envelope. I'd try popping the code in your main view's script tags and insert an alert or console.log to make sure it's capturing the value. Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess I should, perhaps, start with something simpler:  
 How would I go about capturing the onChange event of

`<td class="dataCell">@(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.RetainedCWT).Min(0))</td>`
  
 ?

Comment: @PKD The snippet that I posted has an event handler using the ID jQuery selector for your IntegerTextBox. I would inspect that item in the rendered markup to make sure the ID is "RetainedCWT".

Comment: Absolutely understand that... Just not sure about the "kendoIntegerTextBox" part, as that's not what it's referred to in my code, and using what _is_ in my code doesn't seem to work. :)

Comment: Your main view code is using model binding for the IntegerTextBox (which really IMO should be a NumericTextBox--esp when we're trying to attach to an event) with the lambda expression IntegerTextBoxFor(model=> model.RetainedCWT). You could try Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.RetainedCWT) and then modify the javascript snippet in my example to '.kendoNumericTextBox({...'